# Update mysql value with a Bash variable

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, sql-update, command-line-interface

I want to update a mysql db from a Bash script setting the value to a variable from the same script.

```
IP=$1
IP="xmpp:`echo $IP`:5222"
#IP='10.10.10.122'
echo $IP

mysql -ulol -plol -Ae 'update cs.load_b set dest_uri="$IP" where group_id="1" limit 1;'
mysql -ulol -plol -Ae 'select * from cs.load_b;'
```

The code is executed as follows:

```
./dbup.sh 10.10.10.122
```

Currently the update sets the value to `$IP`:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+----+----------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| id | g_id     | dest_uri   | resources    | p_mode     | desc        |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
|  2 |        1 | $IP        | xmpp=300     |          0 |             |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

I expect:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+----+----------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| id | g_id     | dest_uri   | resources    | p_mode     | desc        |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
|  2 |        1 | xmpp:10.10.10.122:5222|xmpp=300|     0 |             |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

Mysql version 5.7.17, CentOS 7

---

Response to chepner:

```
 48 # Network Address qualifier
 49 qualify_ip() {
 50     echo ".................................................."
 51     if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
 52             OIFS=$IFS
 53             IFS='.'
 54             ip=($1)
 55             IFS=$OIFS
 56             [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
 57                 && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
 58             echo ".................................................."
 59             echo "$1 is a valid network address"
 60             echo ".................................................."
 61     else
 62             echo ".................................................."
 63             echo "$1 is not a valid network address. Exiting."
 64             echo ".................................................."
 65             exit 1
 66     fi
 67     echo ".................................................."
 68 }
..
365 qualify_ip $IP
```

I was only including what was necessary for the question.

Comment: What is the value of `$PUBLIC_IP` here?

Comment: More importantly, what are you doing to validate the value of `PUBLIC_IP` before you use it to construct an SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
mysql -ulol -plol -Ae 'update cs.load_b set dest_uri="$IP" where group_id="1" limit 1;'
```

to

```
mysql -ulol -plol -Ae "update cs.load_b set dest_uri='$IP' where group_id=1 limit 1;"
```

So that your variable `IP` gets expanded by shell.  We are also taking advantage of the fact that MySQL honors both `''` and `""` for string literals.  Also, `group_id` columns seems to be a number.  In that case, we don't need to enclose `1` in single quotes.

Lastly, you could use `$()` (command substitution) instead of backticks while setting the value for `IP`:

```
IP="xmpp:$(echo $PUBLIC_IP):5222"
```

You can even eliminate `$()` since it a simple variable expansion:

```
IP="xmpp:$PUBLIC_IP:5222"
```

Comment: Also can you add up a point to avoid usage of ```` inside setting of `IP` variable and recommend using command substitution?

Comment: @Alex: Since you are new here, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: That works! I tried quite a few syntaxes, glad to have it working. Thanks @codeforester. Also -- thanks @nian. I now have: `IP=$1` `mysql -ulol -plol -Ae "update cs.load_b set dest_uri='xmpp:$IP:5060' where group_id=1 limit 1;"`